# Deleting row from table using mysql

Tags: java, mysql

table1

```
id   type       name       parent    group_id
1    special    name1      0         21
2    Group      name2      1         19
3    Group      name3      1         22
4    special    name4      0         89
```

table2

```
id   version    mcs        user    right_id
1    0          15          27          3
2    0          15          27          4
```

And right_id in table2 references on id in table1.
What i want is to delete the rows in table1 where name = name2 and name3.
How to make this?

Comment: Do you have foreign key constraint for right_id column?

Comment: yes i have a key cons.

Comment: If you have key constraint as 'delete cascade' than you can use simple delete query on parent table itself.

Comment: sorry .. i checked and found that there is no constraint

Comment: ohk.. I have posted query as an answer.You can use that if you don't have constraint but its good practice to use constraints whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use below mentioned query to delete required data from both tables

```
 delete * from table1 as a join table2 as b on a.id=b.right_id where 
 a.name in ('name2','name3')
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to above answers, if you want that on deletion of any row in the parent table table1 , automatically a row in the table2 having value of right_id same as value of id in table1 should be deleted then you need to use ON DELETE CASCADE clause in the create script of your table2.

See this http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php

Comment: Its difficult to get a privilege but it is more difficult to use it responsibly.Please can I request an explanation for the down vote.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below query which will delete records from both the tables:

```
DELETE a,b FROM table2 AS a 
INNER JOIN table1 AS b ON a.right_id = b.id 
WHERE b.name IN ('name1', 'name2');
```

Comment: it says unknown column name !!

Comment: there is no column named name in table1

Comment: As you mentioned in question, there is a column named name in table1. Please see your original table and update the query as per the column name

Answer (score -2):

```
DELETE FROM table1 AS A 
INNER JOIN table2 AS B ON A.ID = B.RIGHT_ID 
WHERE A.NAME IN (name1, name2)
```